# Run a Google Apps Script from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Chrome Extension development and I want to run an apps script from the extension when I click the button from extension. But I'm not sure how to do it and I've checked the guide but couldn't catch the idea. Here are my codes,

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnGet').click(function () {
        $(document).load('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwpkBW7qKZBeJ011C7j3le4vV8D0SEHu9709mWtEMzJgrJmHnaR/exec');
    });
});
```

**Apps Script**

```
function doGet(e){
  function newEntry() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.getRange(lr+1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([["First Name", "Last Name", "Email"]]);
    Browser.msgBox("New Entry Added!");
  }
}
```

I've managed to run codes from my `script.js` but I'm not sure how can I run codes from my apps script. How can I run the codes from my apps script?

Comment: please read this : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Your question is not clear, because you've posted code that cannot possibly work. (`newEntry()` is a function inside a function, and is never invoked within that closure.) As Serge suggests, start with getting your Google Apps Script web application to work independently of the Chrome Extension, then move on to integrating the two.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Instead of

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

try

```
var id = 'spreadsheet-id'; //replace with your spreadsheet id
var sheetName = 'sheet name'; //replace with your sheet name.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByID(id);
var sheet = ss.getSheetbyName(sheetName);
```

## Explanation

The methods that return spreadsheet active objects can be used when the script is being called from the spreadsheet. doGet(e) could interact with a spreadsheet but you should specify which is the one that you want to work on.

## References

- [openByID(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)